# Tracking subs referral

Tags: youtube-api

Is it possible using the current APIs to track where one's subscribers are subscribing from?

For example perhaps I want to see how many subscribers an annotation on a certain video (that any user uploaded) generated for my channel.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to what you're describing is running a YouTube Analytics API report with

```
ids=channel==UC...
dimensions=video
metrics=subscribersGained,subscribersLost
sort=-subscribersGained
```

This will return the top ten videos that led to subscriptions to your channel. But I don't think that videos uploaded in third-party channels that have annotations prompting people to subscribe to your channel will show up on that list. My understanding is that only videos in your own channel will show up on the list, and it might be that only subscriptions made via the Subscribe link on the web page (not via an annotation) would trigger inclusion on that report.

Sorry that I don't have more specific details.